# The right way to call the MembershipProvider methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

On my CreateUserWizard, I'm invoking additional properties and when I call GetUser(), I receive:
*"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"* 
The codebehind of Registration.aspx:

```
        NCCMembershipUser currentUser = (NCCMembershipUser)Membership.GetUser();
        Guid id = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        ...assigning control values to membership values...

        try
        {
            NCCMembershipProvider u = (NCCMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
            u.UpdateUser(currentUser);
        }
```

Should I not be using GetUser to access the properties?

Here's the GetUser method:

```
    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserID," +
            " Email," +
            " Comment," +
            " PasswordQuestion," +
            " IsApproved," +
            " LastActivityDate," +
            " LastLoginDate," +
            " LastPasswordChangedDate," +
            " CreationDate," +
            " IsLockedOut," +
            " LastLockedOutDate," +
            " UserSalutation," +
            " UserFirstName," +
            " UserLastName," +
            " UserPosition," +
            " UserCompany," +
            " UserCompanyType," +
            " UserCompanyTypeOther," +
            " UserAccountType," +
            " UserAddress1," +
            " UserAddress2," +
            " UserCity," +
            " UserStateProv," +
            " UserPostal," +
            " UserCountry," +
            " UserWebsite," +
            " UserPhone," +
            " UserPhoneExt," +
            " UserFax," +
            " UserIP," +
            " UserIPLastLogin," +
            " IsSubscribed," +
            " LikeAreaRugs," +
            " LikeCarpeting," +
            " LikeCoverings," +
            " LikeComponents," +
            " LikeHotel," +
            " LikeAccessories" +
            " FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email AND ApplicationName = @ApplicationName", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = username;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = m_ApplicationName;

        NCCMembershipUser u = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                u = GetUserFromReader(reader);

                if (userIsOnline)
                {
                    SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Users " +
                        "SET LastActivityDate = @LastActivityDate " +
                        "WHERE Email = @Email AND ApplicationName = @ApplicationName", conn);

                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastActivityDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = username;
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = m_ApplicationName;

                    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//<<------Error:"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."
                }
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            if (WriteExceptionsToEventLog)
            {
                WriteToEventLog(e, "GetUser(String, Boolean)");

                throw new ProviderException(exceptionMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) { reader.Close(); }

            conn.Close();
        }

        return u;
    }
```

Comment: There is no reason you can't call members off Membership at will. This seems to me to be a bug with whatever `NCCMembershipProvider` is.

Comment: I have a separate custom membership provider, but the code is right off of MSDN. I'll post the GetUser method now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Close` the reader before you issue the update statement.

```
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            u = GetUserFromReader(reader);

            reader.Close();

            if (userIsOnline)
            {
                SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Users " +
                    "SET LastActivityDate = @LastActivityDate " +
                    "WHERE Email = @Email AND ApplicationName = @ApplicationName", conn);

                updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@LastActivityDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = username;
                updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = m_ApplicationName;

                updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            reader.Close()
        }

    }
```

Comment: That definitely helped. It no longer gives me that error. But I'm getting _InvalidCastException_ on the line `NCCMembershipUser u = (NCCMembershipUser)Membership.GetUser();` after it is done going through the method. I'm new to .NET and C#, but something doesn't feel logical about the way it's communicating with the Membership Provider. I simply want to post my values into the current User's database row. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @RyanJMcGowan Check the type returned by `Membership.GetUser();` without casting it to confirm the issue. It is the standard way of using the membership provider API. With a little bit of debugging you would be able to find the issue.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this. `GetUser` returns a `MembershipUser`. I believe the issue is that `MembershipUser` has fewer parameters than my custom `NCCMembershipProvider` so it doesn't cast. I have two override overloads for GetUser: `GetUser(username string, bool userIsOnline)` and `GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline)`, but I need to use `GetUser()` to return the current logged in user. It looks like `GetUser()` can't be overridden. So `membership.GetUser()` can't reference my full `NCCMembershipUser`.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer and make a new question for this issue.